# Find directory name via file require

Tags: php, directory, require

Trying to run this piece of code with in an `index.php` file for example under the directory `dir/index.php` works like this:

```
print basename(dirname(__FILE__);
// returns 'dir'
```

However, I plan to run this globally on the website. Already setup at the top of each file I have `require('global.php');` which refers to a file at `dir/requisites/global.php`. If I insert the following code (inside of a function named `findDir()`) and call it inside the `index.php` file, rather than returning `dir` like intended, it returns `requisites` for obvious reasons.

Is there a way to be able to essentially find the name of the directory is calling upon (requiring) the `global.php` file? I would run the script on top of each page manually but I'm going for a global function that can be modified once to change something across the entire site.

Thanks in advance internet! <3

Answer (score 0):

```
  $root = dirname(__FILE__);
```

echo $root;

Comment: That doesn't achieve what I'm looking for. Not only does that return the entire path to the directory (which is the reason why I added `basename(...)` into the mix but it still doesn't work from within the `global.php` file, still returning a path to the `requisites` directory.